# Splunk Error: "Could not look up HOME variable"

Tags: linux, shell, sh, splunk

Please help me to understand what this shell script does:

```
# main
for HOST in ${HOSTS}
do
URI=http://${HOST}:80
count=99
result=`/opt/splunk/bin/splunk search "index=${INDEX} sourcetype=${SOURCETYPE} SPLUNK_HEALTH_CHECK |stats count" -earliest_time ${EARLIEST} -latest_time ${LATEST} -uri ${URI} -auth ${USER}:${PASS} -preview F -output csv -timeout ${TIMEOUT} 2>&1 |grep -v count |tr -d '\n' |sed 's/"//g'`
if expr $result : '[0-9]*' > /dev/null 2>&1; then

count=$result
result="OK"
fi
date +"%Y-%m-%d %T sh=${HOST} status=\"${result}\" delay_status=$count"
done
```

While calling this script from splunk, I get the following error:

> status="Could not look up HOME variable.  Auth tokens cannot be
>   cached.10" delay_status=99

Comment: Not knowing _splunk_, my guess is (from the error message), that the environment variable `HOME` is not set, although this would be odd. You could do a `printenv HOME` or (depending on your system) a `/usr/sbin/printenv HOME` before calling `splunk`, to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

`Could not look up HOME variable. Auth tokens cannot be cached`

This error usually occurs when trying to run Splunk as the `root` user or permissions are incorrectly set. In your case, you are passing the USER and PASS into script, but bash does not correctly expand these values (see https://answers.splunk.com/answers/446944/getting-error-could-not-look-up-home-variable-auth.html ).

Comment: The link actually states that it does expand, but with double quotes